# getJSON need help passing values

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to use getJSON to load the ids that are stored into a database, i am passing the values from PHP to JavaScript by echoing it out. I am trying to alert the value that i passed through but it didn't work

The PHP and JavaScript are on the same page. Any guidance would be appreciated

I printed the JSON file and it is in this format

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 213
    [1] => 214
    [2] => 215

)
```

PHP

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address");

$arra = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $arra[] = $row['id']; 

}
```

Javascript

```
<script>

var test= <?php echo json_encode($arra); ?> 

var url = test;
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      alert(url);
})

</script>
```

Comment: if they are in the same page y do you need AJAX ?, since PHP is interpreted when loading the page for one time ?

Comment: the database is always updating so i need to fetch the new information using getJSON

Comment: this will load the JS too, maybe you need to separate them and the url variable should contains a link to that page

Comment: url should be the url to which the request will be sent right? not the json data.

Comment: check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for more example of using .getJSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make new php file called "Data.php" and make it return your JSON data.

```
<?php

     $con =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('test');

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address ORDER BY id DESC");

$arra = array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $arra[] = $row['id']; 


}

echo json_encode($arra);

?>
```

Then where you call your $.getJSON, Do:

```
$.getJSON(data.php, function(data) {
      alert(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

url is json object in your case. It should be url of a page! something like this should work:

```
$.getJSON("<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>", test, function(data) {
      alert(data);
})
```